# Android Studio don't recognise signing configuration declared in a properties file

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following key store info store in `keystore.properties` in root folder

```
storePassword=******
keyPassword=******
keyAlias=******
storeFile=/home/jerry/jerryKeyStore
```

and the following gradle code to load it

```
// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

When I open the signing tab of project structure window, Android Studio reads `Unrecognized value` in all signing fields.
It also can't install the APK on my device, throwing an error that APK was built with different key.. as I built it with signing info written directly into the gradle file

I use the following 
Android Studio: 2.1.2
Gradle: 2.1.0

Comment: I have the very same problem now.  I am using Android Studio 2.3.1 on mac.  I'm getting Unrecognized Value in all the signing fields except the "Store File" one.  Not sure why it finds that value ok in the keystore.properties file but not the others.

Comment: Try to configure it via the module options.. I do that and it works for me .. it will also handle the gradle files

Comment: Thanks Shady. I actually just figured out my problem.  I'll add it as an answer.  It may help someone.

Comment: I too have this issue. I don't want the keys made public in the gradle file. I wonder how many GitHub repos currently expose their passwords like this...

Comment: Oh, whoops, I just needed to rebuild my project

Comment: you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        ......
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
    }
}
```

in module.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the accuracy of the 'keyAlias'.  You should probably also be suspicious about the 'storeFile'.  I say this because I had a very similar problem and because I had misspelled keyAlias it prevented the system from accessing the file and that is surely why I was getting "Unrecognized Value".  But it could easily be the fact that you don't have a .jks extension on your store file reference, or perhaps simply that you have the path wrong, or have located the file in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was quotation marks in the keystore.properties values.  I took out the quotes, rebuilt, and it ran fine.  I still see "unrecognized values" in the project structure window but no more missing keystores.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the "Unrecognized value" errors. Do this to fix it:

- Open Project Structure (Ctrl Shift Alt S)
- On the left bar, under Modules, click "app", click "Build Types" tab, click "Release".
- Change Signing Config to "config"/etc.

Then the Play button will work properly.

---

To fix your "APK was built with different key" error, uninstall the debug app before installing the release APK.